# Expand Sine and Cosine

Tags: code-golf, trigonometry

Trigonometry has LOTS of identities. So many that you can expand most functions into sines and cosines of a few values. The task here is to do that in the fewest bytes possible.

## Identity list

Well, the ones we're using here.

```
sin(-x)=-sin(x)
sin(π)=0
cos(-x)=cos(x)
cos(π)=-1
sin(a+b)=sin(a)*cos(b)+sin(b)*cos(a)
cos(a+b)=cos(a)cos(b)-sin(a)sin(b)
```

For the sake of golfing, I've omitted the identities that can be derived from these. You are free to encode double-angles and such but it may cost you bytes.

## Input

- You should take in an expression as a string with an arbitrary number of terms consisting of a coefficient and some sine and cosine functions, each with an exponent and an arbitrary number of arguments.
- Coefficients will always be nonzero integers.
- Each argument will be a coefficient, followed by either a single latin letter or pi.
- You can decide whether to take in pi as `pi` or `π`. Either way remember that you're scored in bytes, not characters.

## Output

Output the same expression, but…

- All trig functions are either `sin` or `cos`.
- All arguments of trig functions are single variables, with no coefficients.
- All like terms are combined.
- Terms with a coefficient of 0 are removed.
- All factors in the same term that are the same function of the same variable are condensed into a single function with an exponent.

Note: Leading `+` signs are allowed, but not required. `a+-b` is allowed, and equivalent to `a-b`. If there are no terms with nonzero coefficients, then output either `0` or an empty string.

## Worked Example

We'll start with `sin(-3x)+sin^3(x)`. The obvious first thing to do would be to deal with the sign using the parity identity, leaving `-sin(3x)`. Next I can expand `3x` into `x+2x`, and apply the sine additive identity recursively:

```
-(sin(x)cos(2x)+cos(x)sin(2x))+sin^3(x)
-(sin(x)cos(2x)+cos(x)(sin(x)cos(x)+sin(x)cos(x)))+sin^3(x)
```

Next, some distributive property and like terms:

```
-sin(x)cos(2x)-2cos^2(x)sin(x)+sin^3(x)
```

Now, I expand the `cos(2x)` and apply the same reduction:

```
-sin(x)(cos(x)cos(x)-sin(x)sin(x))-2cos^2(x)sin(x)+sin^3(x)
-sin(x)cos^2(x)+sin^3(x)-2cos^2(x)sin(x)+sin^3(x)
2sin^3(x)-3sin(x)cos^2(x)
```

And now, it's finished!

## Test Cases

In addition to the following, all of the individual identities (above) are test cases. Correct ordering is neither defined nor required.

```
cos(2x)+3sin^2(x) => cos^2(x)+2sin^2(x)
sin(-4x) => 4sin^3(x)cos(x)-4sin(x)cos^3(x)
cos(a+2b-c+3π) => 2sin(a)sin(b)cos(b)cos(c)-sin(a)sin(c)cos^2(b)+sin(a)sin(c)sin^2(b)-cos(a)cos^2(b)cos(c)+cos(a)sin^2(b)cos(c)-2cos(a)sin(b)cos(b)sin(c)
sin(x+674868986π)+sin(x+883658433π) => 0 (empty string works too)
sin(x+674868986π)+sin(x+883658434π) => 2sin(x)
```

…and may the shortest program in bytes win.

Comment: May we output (for example) `sin(x)^3` rather than `sin^3(x)`? Can we take pi as `PI` as well?

Comment: This looks very close to a dup of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38341/help-me-with-trigonometry

Comment: @DigitalTrauma that seems to be about printing a specific answer set, not a generalized and specified input-processing challenge.

Comment: @Giuseppe sure, whatever format is best.

Comment: I presume it's okay to have a constant (i.e. not a coefficient of sin or cos) in the output, since it's possible to deduce sin^2 + cos^2 = 1 only using the identities given?

Comment: @JungHwanMin how so? (Though you will encounter constants, like cos(π).)

Comment: `cos(0) = cos(pi+(-pi)) = cos(pi)cos(-pi) - sin(pi)sin(-pi) = cos(pi)cos(pi) - 0 = (-1)^2 = 1`. So, `1 = cos(0) = cos(x+(-x)) = cos(x)cos(-x) - sin(x)sin(-x) = cos(x)cos(x) + sin(x)sin(x) = cos^2(x) + sin^2(x)`.

Comment: Is it fine to simplify `sin^2 + cos^2` to `1`?

Comment: @JungHwanMin yeah, that's fine, but it's not strictly required. As long as the output has no like terms or factors and is fully expanded, it's fine.

Comment: @JungHwanMin It must be, as it stems from applying the last identity with `b=-a` and then the first and third

Comment: "*Coefficients and will always be nonzero integers*" must be missing a word (or has a word too many). Sorry, should have caught this in sandbox.

Comment: @PeterTaylor it's never too late to fix a typo!

Comment: Are built-ins allowed? (I am thinking of doing this in Mathematica, with TrigExpand)

Comment: @NoOneIsHere yes, but I won't upvote it because it's zero-effort.

Comment: This looked very easy to me before I actually read it.

Comment: @JungHwanMin Wow. I predicted that it may be possible to deduce sin²x+cos²x=1 while it was in the sandbox, but could not prove it. Now it's indeed true.

Comment: "You should take in an expression as a string"<- Is this a strict requirement? For eg. Julia has an`Expr` type for expressions, can the input be of`Expr` type? Also, will the operation between terms in the expression always be addition? Is `sin(-3x)-sin^3(x)` a possible input?

Comment: @sundar yes, that would be a possible input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bracmat](https://github.com/BartJongejan/Bracmat), 221 bytes

```
(P=F v a b.!arg:((sin|cos):?F.?v)&(!v:@&(!F.!v)|!F$!v)|!arg:%?a_%?b&(P$!a)_(P$!b)|!arg)&(f=i a b n u.1+(!arg:e^(?n*((i|-i):?i)*?u+?b)&(!i*(sin.!u)+(cos.!u))^!n*f$(e^!b)|!arg:%?a_%?b&(f$!a)_(f$!b)|!arg)+-1)&(Z=.f$(P$!arg))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7NboMwEITvfQosEbK2haUESl0k5J4455wDkY0gtdRCxF858O7UBlKuvXhXszPzWTUy/5bdPMMlSZ3BkY5iSDb3GKDV1ZTXLY5FysSAPUBD/GHelKEBTyh1l2G9ByFvB6E8uLhI4psdaj2ZVJlo2@pUTs9OFJZAkYGoCICefG36NSaip0JZhiYWzFCPKRi6XXCGKlK6UGTP2p1YrsRyJ1L/ZHquCTMJ@x8j4fnn8@sI96I7xqIYH03RtrquvLrv3KuLdgXPC/xMRvyy0NfNan5gVrqsI86C/UwD8lTPmzX8y0t6Jsr8iOTG9tBb10ijt5BH/J1HVtxaKedB9MrD4P/OcHH@Ag)

Comment: I have no idea what that's doing but it works... good answer on an otherwise-abandoned question!

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 841 bytes

Longer than I hoped, but the logic is straightforward.

```py
E=enumerate
S,O='sin','cos'
def f(e):
 e=[[(a,b,[([1,-1][j<0]*([1,j]['pi'==C]),C)for j,C in c for _ in range(1,abs(j)+1 if'pi'!=C else 2)],d)for a,b,c,d in i]for i in e]
 P=1
 while P:
  P=0
  for i,a in E(e):
   F=0
   for I,A in E(a):
    if len(A[2])>1:q,*w=A[2];l=[[(A[0],S,[q],1),(1,O,w,1)],[(A[0],S,w,1),(1,O,[q],1)]]if S==A[1]else[[(A[0],O,[q],1),(1,O,w,1)],[(-1*A[0],S,[q],1),(1,S,w,1)]];l=[u+a[:I]+a[I+1:]for u in l];e=e[:i]+e[i+1:]+l;F=1;break
   if F:P=1;break
 r={}
 for i in e:
  R,T={},1
  for a,b,[(C,V)],d in i:
   if C==-1 and'sin'==b:a*=-1
   if'pi'==V:
    if(L:=[[1,-1][abs(C)%2],0][b==S])==0:R,T={},0;break
    else:T*=L*a
   else:R[(b,V)]=R.get((b,V),0)+d;T*=a
  r[M]=r.get(M:=str(sorted(R.items())),0)+T
 return' + '.join(str(b)+''.join(f'{j}{["^"+str(l),""][l==1]}({k})'for(j,k),l in eval(a))for a,b in r.items()if b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVTdbtowFL7PU3igKTZxKkwyxsI8qUKtVKlVK6h6Y7lTAqYNTUMbYDAhpL3hHokd2yTQtap2sxvr/H7nOz/J08/5/TQPOk/FdnvCVb54VEU8V86AXnJ3luYudYfTmeuM1BiNsSKRgxQXAsc0oQILRn0mxeRrUza0MpHCfUpdznuS0B4ZTws0oT2U5miItPJdi0Wc3ynMaJzM8IR4DKVjnfSB95DKZgq1iKQjk6uLDOlIJ6VSG1ItKumgK84ctLxPM4WugBLoTXhNCI110InlitCp8RjXGT22rti6oDDKVI6PRUuSbyx6po0l10o30y0ei6akAyqeJWWEAuFLugRJ0sq1rBw2SEpAHHDAYFK3UoJcvgnis8arEhZTGgYLLxbRmYT3zGOR6X@h@Weyq7gSUSo9JVLt8rLuKWfdpFDxg2P7Oo2u9paCrzcO2g9Qd9@n12ClbDc2u88evdHDNwOPdkg9zn2G4nxkzoHzJIobYLFeu@2bcpz4PILJ2aPQ6@2Rjy1Jm1IknA8k4bwZ7eo292zN1qPrBj9vxE6p9gVONBneP7pTc2wU2iTeqAuBOqwQF5IXxnkR8dm8wLNpMVcj3D9K5@pxhgkxCdfQvpovitxFHnKPJtM0xzo6IZ67U8fuerJZi9ptzdOejNBaTYqMcyY3eP2wIS5MCE/oA6GZmd@POIMbKk/U3HRZFAaWkK1jvhFGkf2EECw7AGXlwnSR3f6hk1W@AHaP6mCHhBXxQLgN8Io4T0Waz7H@AAmqt0qzH@jIFYEv9Lalw2xmCNJrAuEhAfkSMSwRAUnjhntcU96pa0fstRJ/6AW/fx3g679D2UPsEopwC6TESL4JMKJuH27l7fK6IRiofhNDwb5D4u8dw12XiZlKZdTEtdE3BKsYm@5ZYxmzw2xV1qqaxXLs/FZe@3PYaXe@dNrQqWdNnU7Q/tQJg5fN/7VA6LNKfdFvGfM6vsJ9bz6u@y/Uwv9ELXyPWhVkKwfUAh3eA6vuYXcO9ld5iFMm72mURff3tCuP6u3DzR2ibP8A)

Comment: Without changing the algorithm, I get 814 chars. First half:  `E=enumerate
S,O='sin','cos'
def f(e):
 e=[[(a,b,[([1,-1][j<0]*[1,j]['pi'==C],C)for j,C in c for _ in range(1,1+abs(j)if'pi'!=C else 2)],d)for a,b,c,d in i]for i in e]
 P=1
 while P:
  P=0
  for i,a in E(e):
   for I,A in E(a):
    if len(A[2])>1:q,*w=A[2];l=[[(A[0],S,[q],1),(1,O,w,1)],[(A[0],S,w,1),(1,O,[q],1)]]if S==A[1]else[[(A[0],O,[q],1),(1,O,w,1)],[(-1*A[0],S,[q],1),(1,S,w,1)]];l=[u+a[:I]+a[I+1:]for u in l];e=e[:i]+e[i+1:]+l;P=1;break
   if P:break`

Comment: Second half: `r={}
 for i in e:
  R,T={},1
  for a,b,[(C,V)],d in i:
   if C==-1 and S==b:a*=-1
   if'pi'==V:
    if(L:=(1-2*(abs(C)%2))*(b!=S))==0:R,T={},0;break
    else:T*=L*a
   else:R[(b,V)]=R.get((b,V),0)+d;T*=a
  r[M]=r.get(M:=str(sorted(R.items())),0)+T
 return' + '.join(str(b)+''.join(f'{j}{f"^{l}"*(l!=1)}({k})'for(j,k),l in eval(a))for a,b in r.items()if b)`

Comment: @movatica Thank you very much. I have added the essence of your golfs to the post, will complete it when time allows...

Comment: Saving more bytes using exponent to replace conditionals: `e=[[(a,b,[([1,-1][j<0]*j**('pi'==C),C)for j,C in c for _ in range(1,1+abs(j)**('pi'!=C))],d)for a,b,c,d in i]for i in e]`

Comment: ... and finally, `-1` is a True-value in Python3, allowing to turn around the conditional: `if(L:=(1-2*(abs(C)%2))*(b!=S)):T*=L*a
    else:R,T={},0;break`