# Symbolic Integration of Polynomials

Tags: code-golf, math, parsing, polynomials, calculus

Apply an indefinite integral to a given string. The only rules you will be using are defined as such:

```
∫cx^(n)dx = (c/(n+1))x^(n+1) + C, n ≠ -1
c, C, and n are all constants.
```

## Specifications:

- You must be able to integrate polynomials with any of the possible features:

  - A coefficient, possibly a fraction in the format `(numerator/denominator)`.
  - Recognition that e and π are constants, and in their use, be able to form fractions or expressions containing them (can be held in a fraction like `(e/denominator)` or `(numerator/e)`, or, if in exponents, `x^(e+1)`)

    - Aside of these two special constants, all coefficients will be rational, real numbers.
  - An exponent, possibly a fraction, in the format `x^(exponent)`

    - Expressions with `e` or `π` in them, aside of themselves, will not be in exponents. (you will not have to integrate stuff like `x^(e+1)`, but you might integrate `x^(e)`)
  - Can use non-x 1-char variables (i.e. `f`)

    - This is only for ASCII ranges 65-90 and 97-122.
  - You do not have to use chain rule or integrate `x^(-1)`.
- Output must have padding (separation between terms, i.e. `x^2 + x + C`.
- If it is unknown how to integrate with the above features, the program should print out `"Cannot integrate "+input`.
- It must be a full program.

## Bonuses:

- -10% if you print out the "pretty" exponents formatted for markdown (instead of `x^2`, `x<sup>2</sup>`).
- -10% if you print out the equation (i.e. `∫xdx = (1/2)x^2 + C`)

## Examples:

Input:

```
x
```

Output:

```
(1/2)x^(2) + C
```

---

Input:

```
-f^(-2)
```

Output:

```
f^(-1) + C
```

---

Input:

```
(1/7)x^(1/7) + 5
```

Output:

```
(1/56)x^(8/7) + 5x + C
```

---

Input:

```
πx^e
```

Output:

```
(π/(e+1))x^(e+1) + C
```

---

Input:

```
(f+1)^(-1)
```

Output:

```
Cannot integrate (f+1)^(-1)
```

Comment: Surprised we don't already have this question - but I couldn't find a dup. +1

Comment: @DigitalTrauma There is [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54162/44713), though.

Comment: 1. I presume that other than `e` and `π`, the only values in coefficients will be rational numbers? I.e. it's not necessary to handle multivariable polynomials? 2. When you say "*non-x 1-char variables*", are you restricting to `a-zA-Z` or do you intend to include other Unicode ranges?

Comment: Dang, I was going to post this at some point. Oh well.

Comment: Do you think there should be a bonus if someone's program prints `ln(x) + C` for an input of `x^(-1)`?

Comment: @Ampora No - that opens up a whole can of worms dealing with coefficients of ln.

Comment: Do you really need to print a 27-char string `Cannot integrate polynomial`?

Comment: @xnor `Cannot integrate `, and yes.

Comment: What would ```πe``` integrate as? Would ```e``` be considered as ```exp(1)```, or as a variable? If the former, would we assume ```x``` to be the variable?

Comment: @TomCarpenter `πe` would integrate as a constant, so it would integrate to `(πe)x`. I wouldn't make a coefficient this complicated, so you may assume that this will be an untested input.

Comment: How are we supposed to solve the halting problem?

Comment: @FlagAsSpam I misread your question. For the general case, computing integrals involves solving the halting problem since e^(ax^2) is integrable if and only if `a` is always 0, but being able to show that is equal to the halting problem.

Comment: So it is necessary for it to only solve the polynomial integrals? Are built-ins allowed?

Comment: @TanMath Yes and yes, but make sure you do output "Cannot integrate " for things that are more difficult than just power rule.

Comment: a few questions for clarification:
`x^(e+1)` is given as an example of how transcendentals may appear in an exponent, but also as an example of how they won't. -> !?
Also, could there ever be multiple letter variables, if so how to choose which to integrate over? May we use `pi` or `p` for `π`?
Lastly, is the output supposed to be concise, and if so how is that defined? f.x. is `(1/7)x^(1/7)` to `(1/8)x^(1/7+1) + C` ok?

Comment: @LeifWillerts 1) I meant that `x^(e+1)` will not be an integrand, but it may be the result of an integration. 2) There will not be multiple letter variables. 3) Yes. 4) Yes, but it should be `(1/56)x^(1/7+1) + C` (I made a mistake in the examples).

Comment: Now that I can comment: I assumed that C is also not going to be an input variable but reserved for the integration constant. Otherwise, of course, this would need to be clarified and the code changed accordingly.

Comment: @senegrom Yes, that's correct. c: Nice answer, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mathematica 478 * 0.9 = 430.2

```
φ=(α=ToExpression;Π=StringReplace;σ="Cannot integrate "<>#1;Λ=DeleteDuplicates@StringCases[#1,RegularExpression["[a-df-zA-Z]+"]];μ=Length@Λ;If[μ>1,σ,If[μ<1,Λ="x",Λ=Λ[[1]]];Ψ=α@Π[#1,{"e"->" E ","π"->" π "}];Φ=α@Λ;Θ=α@Π[#1,{"e"->" 2 ","π"->" 2 "}];λ=Exponent[Θ,Φ,List];Θ=Simplify[Θ*Φ^Max@@Abs@λ];Θ=PowerExpand[Θ/.Φ->Φ^LCM@@Denominator@λ];If[Coefficient[Ψ,Φ,-1]==0&&PolynomialQ[Θ,Φ],"∫("<>#1<>")d"<>Λ<>" = "<>Π[ToString[Integrate[Ψ,Φ],InputForm],{"E"->"e","Pi"->"π"}]<>" + C",σ]])&
```

This creates a true function φ that takes one String as Input.
(Does that count as complete program for Mathematica?)

The ungolfed version would be:

```
φ=(
    σ="Cannot integrate "<>#1;
    Λ=DeleteDuplicates@StringCases[#1,RegularExpression["[a-df-zA-Z]+"]];
    If[Length@Λ>1,σ,
        If[Length@Λ<1,Λ="x",Λ=Λ[[1]]];
        Ψ=ToExpression@StringReplace[#1,{"e"->" E ","π"->" π "}];
        Φ=ToExpression@Λ;
        Θ=ToExpression@StringReplace[#1,{"e"->" 2 ","π"->" 2 "}];
        λ=Exponent[Θ,Φ,List];
        Θ=Simplify[Θ*Φ^Max@@Abs@λ];
        Θ=PowerExpand[Θ/.Φ->Φ^LCM@@Denominator@λ];
        If[Coefficient[Ψ,Φ,-1]==0&&PolynomialQ[Θ,Φ],
            "∫("<>#1<>")d"<>Λ<>" = "<>StringReplace[ToString[Integrate[Ψ,Φ],InputForm],{"E"->"e","Pi"->"π"}]<>" + C",
            σ
        ]
    ]
)&
```

Note that the Greek letters are necessary to be able to use all the other letters in the input.

Answer (score 7):

## MATLAB, 646 x 0.9 = 581.4 bytes

```
t=input('','s');p=char(960);s=regexprep(t,{p,'pi([a-zA-Z])','([a-zA-Z])pi','([\)e\d])([a-zA-Z])','([a-zA-Z])(([\(\d]|pi))','e^(\(.+?\))','e'},{'pi','pi*$1','$1*pi','$1*$2','$1*$2','exp($1)','exp(1)'});r=[s(regexp(s,'\<[a-zA-Z]\>')),'x'];r=r(1);e=0;try
I=int(sym(strsplit(s,' + ')),r);S=[];for i=I
S=[S char(i) ' + '];end
b=0;o=[];for i=1:nnz(S)
c=S(i);b=b+(c==40)-(c==41);if(c==42&&S(i+1)==r)||(b&&c==32)
c='';end
o=[o c];end
o=regexprep(char([8747 40 t ')d' r ' = ' o 67]),{'pi','exp\(1\)','exp','\^([^\(])',['1/' r]},{p,'e','e^','^($1)',[r '^(-1)']});catch
e=1;end
if e||~isempty(strfind(o,'log'))
disp(['Cannot integrate ' t]);else
disp(o);end
```

This is currently a work-in-progress using MATLABs built in symbolic integration capabilities. Currently the requirements have been updated so the format now matches the requirements. It also does qualify for the second -10% bonus.

If anyone wants to pitch in and suggest ways of correcting the output, or use this code as a basis for another answer, feel free :). If I can find the time, I'll keep playing with it and see if I can think how to reformat the output.

**Update:** Ok, so after a bit more work, here is how the code currently stands. It is still a work in progress, but now getting closer to matching the required output.

```
t=input('','s'); %Get input as a string
p=char(960); %Pi character
s=regexprep(t,{p,'pi([a-zA-Z])','([a-zA-Z])pi','([\)e\d])([a-zA-Z])','([a-zA-Z])(([\(\d]|pi))','e^(\(.+?\))','e'},{'pi','pi*$1','$1*pi','$1*$2','$1*$2','exp($1)','exp(1)'}); %Reformat input to work with built in symbolic integration
r=[s(regexp(s,'\<[a-zA-Z]\>')),'x'];r=r(1); %determine the variable we are integrating
e=0; %Assume success
try
    I=int(sym(strsplit(s,' + ')),r); %Integrate each term seperately to avoid unwanted simplificaiton
    S=[];
    for i=I
        S=[S char(i) ' + ']; %Recombine integrated terms
    end
    %Now postprocess the output to try and match the requirements
    b=0;o=[];
    for i=1:nnz(S)
        %Work through the integrated string character by character
        c=S(i);
        b=b+(c=='(')-(c==')'); %Keep track of how many layers deep of brackets we are in
        if(c=='*'&&S(i+1)==r)||(b&&c==' ') %If a '*' sign preceeds a variable. Also deblank string.
            c=''; %Delete this character
        end
        o=[o c]; %merge into new output string.
    end
    o=regexprep([char(8747) '(' t ')d' r ' = ' o 'C'],{'pi','exp\(1\)','exp','\^([^\(])',['1/' r]},{p,'e','e^','^($1)',[r '^(-1)']});
catch
    e=1; %failed to integrate
end
if e||~isempty(strfind(o,'log'))
    disp(['Cannot integrate ' t])  %bit of a hack - matlab can integrate 1/x, so if we get a log, we pretend it didn't work.
else
    disp(o)% Display it.
end
```

Here are some examples of what it currently produces. As you can see, it's not quite right, but getting closer.

Inputs:

```
x
-f^(-2)
(1/7)x^(1/7) + 5
πx^e
(f+1)^(-1)
```

Outputs:

```
∫(x)dx = x^(2)/2 + C
∫(-f^(-2))df = f^(-1) + C
∫((1/7)x^(1/7) + 5)dx = x^(8/7)/8 + 5x + C
∫(πx^(e))dx = (πx^(e+1))/(e+1) + C
Cannot integrate (f+1)^(-1)
```

Comment: I assume the problem with output that you're having is that the fractions don't simplify/go into a single coefficient?

Comment: @FlagAsSpam, the fractions are simplifying, but the trouble is they end up on the wrong side of the variable. For instance in the third example it results in ```x^(8/7)/8``` which while mathematically correct is not in the form you want it - ```(1/8)x^(8/7)```.

Comment: Considering that you are the only answer so far, I might consider changing that if no more answers come through in a day or two to "any mathematically correct, valid output" for fractions.

Comment: Your answer is valid - You do not have to simplify fractional output anymore. c:

Comment: I will golf it down a bit then and count the bytes.

Comment: Can you use `||nnz()` instead of ~isempty()`. Also, I think you can use `|` instead of `||`, since `e` is a scalar...