# Find the rate of change at a point on a polynomial

Tags: code-golf, math, calculus

Given the equation of a polynomial and an x-coordinate find the rate of change of the point at that x-coord on the curve.

A polynomial is in the form: ax<sup>n</sup> + ax<sup>n-1</sup> + ... + ax<sup>1</sup> + a, where a ϵ Q and n ϵ W. For this challenge, n can also be 0 if you don't want to have to deal with special cases (constants) where there is no x.

To find the rate of change at that x-coord, we can get the derivative of the polynomial and plug in the x-coord.

#### Input

The polynomial can be taken in any reasonable form, but you must state what that format is explicitly. For example, an array of the form `[..[coefficient, exponent]..]` is acceptable.

#### Output

The rate of change of the point at the x-coord given.

#### This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Examples

```
[[4, 3], [-2, 4], [5, 10]]   19    ->   16134384838410
                  [[0, 4]]  400    ->   0
           [[4, 0], [5,1]]  -13    ->   5
      [[4.14, 4], [48, 2]]   -3    ->   -735.12
         [[1, 3], [-5, 0]]    5.4  ->   87.48
```

Comment: Algorithm for anyone who doesn't have the appropriate math background:
The derivative of A*x^B+C*x^D+... is (A*B)*x^(B-1)+(C*D)*x^(D-1)+...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the set W. Is that the natural numbers union 0?

Comment: @AlexA., yes, it is.

Comment: [Borderline dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54162/194)

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think they share a similar idea but I don't think any answer from there could be posted here without very, very significant modification.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Mathematica, 6 bytes

```
#'@#2&
```

(Beat **THAT**, <s>MATL</s> and 05AB1E)

The first argument must be a polynomial, with `#` as its variable and with `&` at the end (i.e. a pure function polynomial; e.g. `3 #^2 + # - 7 &`). The second argument is the x-coordinate of the point of interest.

**Explanation**

```
#'
```

Take the derivative of the first argument (`1` is implied).

```
... @#2&
```

Plug in the second argument.

**Usage**

```
#'@#2&[4 #^3 - 2 #^4 + 5 #^10 &, 19] (* The first test case *)
```

> `16134384838410`

Comment: You win by 0 bytes now :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo When a guy with a chef's knife can tie with a mandoline in a slicing competition, I'll give the point to the guy using the knife. ;)

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
yq^**s
```

Input is: array of exponents, number, array of coefficients.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXFeKipz&input=WzMgNCAxMF0KMTkKWzQgLTIgNV0) Or verify all test cases: [1](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXFeKipz&input=WzMgNCAxMF0KMTkKWzQgLTIgNV0), [2](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXFeKipz&input=WzRdCjQwMApbMF0) [3](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXFeKipz&input=WzAgMV0KLTEzCls0IDVd), [4](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXFeKipz&input=WzQgMl0KLTMKWzQuMTQgNDhd), [5](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eXFeKipz&input=WzMgMF0KLTUuNApbMSAtNV0).

#### Explanation

Consider example inputs `[3 4 10]`, `19`, `[4 -2 5]`.

```
y    % Take first two inputs implicitly and duplicate the first
     %   STACK: [3 4 10], 19, [3 4 10]
q    % Subtract 1, element-wise
     %   STACK: [3 4 10], 19, [2 3 9]
^    % Power, element-wise
     %   STACK: [3 4 10], [361 6859 322687697779]
*    % Multiply, element-wise
     %   STACK: [1083 27436 3226876977790]
*    % Take third input implicitly and multiply element-wise
     %   STACK: [4332 -54872 16134384888950]
s    % Sum of array
     %   STACK: 16134384838410
```

Answer (score 7):

## Julia, <s>45</s> <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```julia
f(p,x)=sum(i->prod(i)x^abs(i[2]-1),p)
```

This is a function that acceps a vector of tuples and a number and returns a number. The absolute value is to ensure that the exponent isn't negative, which necessary because Julia annoying throws a `DomainError` when raising an integer to a negative exponent.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZihwLHgpPXN1bShpLT5wcm9kKGkpeF5hYnMoaVsyXS0xKSxwKQoKdXNpbmcgQmFzZS5UZXN0CkB0ZXN0IGYoWyg0LCAzKSwgKC0yLCA0KSwgKDUsIDEwKV0sIDE5KSA9PSAxNjEzNDM4NDgzODQxMApAdGVzdCBmKFsoMCwgNCldLCA0MDApID09IDAKQHRlc3QgZihbKDQsIDApLCAoNSwgMSldLCAtMTMpID09IDUKQHRlc3QgZihbKDQuMTQsIDQpLCAoNDgsIDIpXSwgLTMpIOKJiCAtNzM1LjEyCkB0ZXN0IGYoWygxLCAzKSwgKC01LCAwKV0sIDUuNCkg4omIIDg3LjQ4CnByaW50bG4oIlRlc3RzIHBhc3MhIik&input=&debug=on) (includes all test cases)

Thanks to Glen O for a couple of corrections and bytes.

Comment: I feared that @AlexA. and Julia broke up, but here they are again, together in harmony <3

Comment: You can save an extra three bytes if, instead of using `i[2]>0&&` to deal with the constant case, you use `abs(i[2]-1)` in the exponent of `x`. And a slightly less clean trick to save another three bytes is to use `p%x` instead of `f(p,x)` - note that you can call it as `%(p,x)` if you want to use it in function form... unfortunately, it seems it doesn't work on TIO (which apparently is running Julia 0.4.6), although it works on my Julia 0.5.0.

Comment: @GlenO Nice, thanks for the suggestions. I went with the `abs` part, but redefining infix operators physically pains me...

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>12</del> 11 bytes

Saved one byte thanks to Adnan.

```
vy¤<²smsP*O

v          For each [coefficient, power] in the input array
 y         Push [coefficient, power]
  ¤<       Compute (power-1)
   ²       Push x value (second input entry)
    sms    Push pow(x, power-1)
       P   Push coefficient * power ( = coefficient of derivative)
        *  Push coefficient * power * pow(x, power-1)
         O Sum everything and implicitly display the result
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dnnCpDzCsnNtc1AqTw&input=W1sxLCAzXSwgWy01LCAwXV0KNS40)

Floating point precision is Python's. I currently swap stack values twice, maybe there is a way to avoid it and save some bytes.

Comment: I believe you can leave out the `}` :).

Comment: `DIs<m**O` is 8 bytes, following the MATL answer that @Luis Mendo provided.

Comment: Even better, `s¹<m**O` is 7 bytes. (http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=c8K5PG0qKk8&input=WzMsNCwxMF0KMTkKWzQsLTIsNV0)

Comment: It changes substantially the input format while I kept the original one. But I agree that manipulating the input format enables shorter answers.

Comment: @Osable true, but others have used that loophole ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 41 bytes

*6 bytes removed thanks to [@AndrasDeak](https://repl.it/EVVA)! In fact, this answer is now more his than mine...*

*Thanks also to [@1Darco1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36671/1darco1) for two corrections!*

```
lambda A,x:sum(a*b*x**(b-1) for a,b in A)
```

Anonymous function that accepts a list of lists with coefficients and exponents (same format as described in the challenge) and a number.

[Try it here](https://repl.it/EVVA).

Comment: Why can you sum `a*x**(b-1)` instead of `a*b*x**(b-1)` ? And further, what if $x=0$ ?

Comment: @1Darco1 You are right on both. I'll change it in a little while

Answer (score 3):

## R, 31 bytes

```
function(a,n,x)sum(a*n*x^(n-1))
```

Anonymous function that takes a vector of coefficients `a`, a vector of exponents `n`, and an `x` value.

Comment: Nice! I added another answer with the same byte count. It uses a completely different approach though. Isn't R amazing?

Comment: Edit: No longer the same byte count :)

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB with Symbolic Math Toolbox, 26 bytes

```
@(p,x)subs(diff(sym(p)),x)
```

This defines an anonymous function. Inputs are:

- a string `p` defining the polynomial, in the format `'4*x^3-2*x^4+5*x^10'`
- a number `x`

Example use:

```
>> f = @(p,x)subs(diff(sym(p)),x)
f = 
    @(p,x)subs(diff(sym(p)),x)

>> f('4*x^3-2*x^4+5*x^10', 19)
ans =
16134384838410
```

Comment: You could use `@(x,p)polyval(polyder(p),x)` in order to gain a byte.

Comment: @flawr Well, he shouldn't now because you just posted that as an answer ;P

Comment: @flawr Thanks, but that's too different, you should post it!

Comment: Well I think you wouldn't have done it anyway, 'cause you'd *gain* a byte =D

Comment: @flawr Aww. I completely misunderstood, haha

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab, 27 bytes

This is an anonymous function that accepts a value `x` and a polyonmial `p` in the form of a list of coefficients, e.g. `x^2 + 2` can be represented as `[1,0,2]`.

```
@(x,p)polyval(polyder(p),x)
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES7), 40 bytes

```
(a,n)=>a.reduce((t,c,i)=>t+i*c*n**--i,0)
```

`a` is an array of the coefficients in ascending exponent order with zeros included e.g. *x*³-5 would be represented by `[-5, 0, 0, 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <strike>31</strike> 27 bytes

Unnamed function taking two inputs `p` and `x`. `p` is assumed to be an R-expression of the polynomial (see example below) and `x` is simply the point of evaluation.

```
function(p,x)eval(D(p,"x"))
```

It works by calling the `D` which computes the symbolic derivative w.r.t. `x` and the evaluates the expression at `x`.

**Example output**

Assuming that the function is now named `f` it can be called in the following way:

```
f(expression(4*x^3-2*x^4+5*x^10),19)
f(expression(0*x^4),400)
f(expression(4*x^0+5*x^1),-13)
f(expression(4.14*x^4+48*x^2),-3)
f(expression(1*x^3-5*x^0),5.4)
```

which respectively produces:

```
[1] 1.613438e+13
[1] 0
[1] 5
[1] -735.12
[1] 87.48
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this! I hadn't considered the possibility of having the input as an expression - this is a really elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

## C++14, <s>165</s> <s>138</s> <s>133</s> <s>112</s> 110 bytes

Generic Variadic Lambda saves a lot. -2 bytes for `#import` and deleting the space before `<`

```c++
#import<cmath>
#define A auto
A f(A x){return 0;}A f(A x,A a,A b,A...p){return a*b*std::pow(x,b-1)+f(x,p...);}
```

Ungolfed:

```c++
#include <cmath>

auto f(auto x){return 0;}

auto f(auto x,auto a,auto b,auto...p){
    return a*b*std::pow(x,b-1)+f(x,p...);
}
```

Usage:

```c++
int main() {
 std::cout << f(19,4,3,-2,4,5,10) << std::endl;
 std::cout << f(400,0,4) << std::endl;
 std::cout << f(-13,4,0,5,1) << std::endl;
 std::cout << f(-3,4.14,4,48,2) << std::endl;
 std::cout << f(5.4,1,3,-5,0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have crossed out all your byte counts. What's the actual byte count, then?

Comment: @numbermaniac thank you, done.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 20 bytes

```
a(f,n)=subst(f',x,n)
```

For example, `a(4*x^3-2*x^4+5*x^10,19)` yields `16134384838410`.

Comment: How the heck does that work?

Comment: @cat It calculates the derivative `f'` of `f`, and then substitutes `n` for `x`.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 33 bytes

```
f x=sum.map(\[c,e]->c*e*x**(e-1))
```

Usage:

```
> f 5.4 [[1, 3], [-5, 0]]
87.48000000000002
```

Answer (score 1):

### dc, 31 bytes

```
??sx0[snd1-lxr^**ln+z2<r]srlrxp
```

Usage:

```
$ dc -e "??sx0[snd1-lxr^**ln+z2<r]srlrxp"
4.14 4 48 2
_3
-735.12
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
{a←⍺⋄+/{×/⍵×a*2⌷⍵-1}¨⍵}
```

Takes polynomial as right argument and value as left argument.

Answer (score 0):

## [DASH](https://github.com/molarmanful/DASH), 33 bytes

```
@@sum(->@* ^#1- :1#0 1(sS *)#0)#1
```

Usage:

```
(
  (
    @@sum(->@* ^#1- :1#0 1(sS *)#0)#1
  ) [[4;3];[_2;4];[5;10]]
) 19
```

## Explanation

```
@@                             #. Curried 2-arg lambda
                               #. 1st arg -> X, 2nd arg -> Y
  sum                          #. Sum the following list:
    (map @                     #. Map over X
                               #. item list -> [A;B]
      * ^ #1 - :1#0 1(sS *)#0  #. This mess is just A*B*Y^(B-1)
    )#1                        #. X
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 46 bytes

```
s=>i=>s map{case(c,e)=>c*e*math.pow(i,e-1)}sum
```

Usage:

```
val f:(Seq[(Double,Double)]=>Double=>Double)=
  s=>i=>s map{case(c,e)=>c*e*math.pow(i,e-1)}sum
print(f(Seq(4.0 → 3, -2.0 → 4, 5.0 → 10))(19))
```

Explanation:

```
s=>                        //define an anonymous function with a parameter s returning
  i=>                        //an anonymous function taking a paramater i and returning
    s map{                   //map each element of s:
      case(c,e)=>              //unpack the tuple and call the values c and e
        c*e*math.pow(i,e-1)    //calculate the value of the first derivate
    }sum                      //take the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom 31 bytes

```
h(q,y)==eval(D(q,x),x,y)::Float
```

results

```
 -> h(4*x^3-2*x^4+5*x^10, 19)
     161343 84838410.0

 -> h(4.14*x^4+48*x^2, -3)
     - 735.12
```

Answer (score 0):

## Casio Basic, 16 bytes

```
diff(a,x)|x=b
```

Input should be the polynomial in terms of `x`. 13 bytes for the code, +3 bytes to enter `a,b` as parameters.

Simply derives expression `a` in respect to `x`, then subs in `x=b`.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 39 bytes

```
lambda p,x:sum(c*e*x**~-e for c,e in p)
```

`lambda` function takes two inputs, `p` and `x`. `p` is the polynomial, given in the example format given in the question. `x` is the x-value at which to find the rate of change.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 14 bytes

```
p->x->eval(p')
```

#### Usage:

```
? (p->x->eval(p'))(4*x^3 - 2*x^4 + 5*x^10)(19)
%1 = 16134384838410
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#TY3BCoAwDEPvfkVvtsqk1Qp60E8RPCgIIkNE/PvZgcJOCU1es8IAwbvxceNyzzv6nII/t@PCFbV4pgYc1KYKJbSmwoTSE2V/iWNIqMzJMZL8E4ROmjSsRL@P2pmprZDm8s1G2NbaSonCCw)

Answer (score 0):

## C, 78 bytes

```C
f(int*Q,int*W,int S,int x){return Q[--S]*W[S]*pow(x,W[S]-1)+(S?f(Q,W,S,x):0);}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 53 bytes

```
#(apply +(for[[c e]%](apply * c e(repeat(dec e)%2))))
```

The polynomial is expressed as a hash-map, keys being coefficients and values are exponents.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 6 chars

```
{⍵⊥⍺}∂
```

For the input of polynom the list

$$ a_n a_{n-1} ... a_1 a_0  $$

means polynom

$$ a_n X^n+a_{n-1} X^{n-1} ... a_1 X+a_0   $$

```
      f←{⍵⊥⍺}∂
      5 4 f ¯13
5
      5 0 0 0 0 0 ¯2 4 0 0 0 f 19
1.613438484E13
      0 0 0 0 0 f 400
0
      0 f 400
0
      4.14 0 48 0 0 f ¯3
¯735.12
      1 0 0 ¯5 f 5.4
87.48
```

Comment: for say the true i dont know why the function polynom is build before derivate