# Rotate the Roots

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

Given a nonzero polynomial with integer coefficients and roots that are on the imaginary and on the real line such that if `a` is a root then so is `-a`, return another polynomial with the roots rotated by 90 degrees.

#### Details

The polynomial can be given in any reasonable format, e.g. as a list of coefficients. The symmetry condition that `a` is a root if and only if `-a` is a root too enforces the rotated polynomial to have real integer coefficients as well.

#### Examples

In the following the polynomials are given as a list of coefficient of the monomials in descending degree. (i.e. the constant comes last)
The polynomial `x^2-1` has roots `{1,-1}`. Rotating them by `90°` means multiplying by `i` (the imaginary unit), so the output polynomial should have the roots `{i,-i}`, which is `x^2 + 1`.

```
Input / Output
[1 0 10 0 -127 0 -460 0 576]  [1 0 -10 0 -127 0 460 0 576]
[1 0 -4 0] [1 0 4 0]
[1] [1]
```

Comment: May I take in the degree of the polynomial as well as the polynomial

Comment: Yes I think that is acceptable.

Comment: All your examples use monic polynomials. Can we assume the input polynomial will be monic? Does the output polynomial *have to* be monic?

Comment: No it can also have other leading coefficients than 1, and the output is also just defined up to a integral multiple.

Comment: It seems the format doesn't have to be a list of coefficients. How far do the reasonable formats go? Can my format be a string expression in the indeterminate `x`, so that my submission can string-replace `x` with `(i*x)`? Can my format a function that evaluates the polynomial, so that my submission is to compose it with the function `x -> i*x`?

Comment: In the coefficient list form, can our output polynomial have leading zeroes?   Can the coefficient be floats like `4.0`? Complex numbers like `4.0+0j`?

Comment: Yes, any of them are acceptable.

Comment: @xnor String representations are valid too as long as they produce integer (i.e. real) coefficients.

Answer (score 12):

### Mathematica, 10 Bytes

Pure function which takes a function of x and substitutes in ix.

```
#/.x->I*x&
```

Alternative with only 7 bytes but not quite sure if it counts. Pure function which takes in a pure function and returns a function of x.

```
#[I*x]&
```

Comment: And you didn't even need any builtins!

Comment: I'm pretty sure a pure function polynomial is a "reasonable format" (like it was [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99373/60043)) It uses `#` as the variable and has a `&` at the end.

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could

Comment: My only concern about the second answer was the mismatch between input (a pure function) and output (a function of x).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Jı*Ċ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@91ZKPWka7D0////x9tqKNgoKNgaACmdA2NzCEMEzOIiKm5WSwA)

### How it works

Multiplies the first element by `1`, the third element by `-1`, etc.

```
Jı*Ċ×  argument: z
J      [1,2,...,len(z)]
 ı     i (the imaginary unit)
  *    to the power of (each element)
   Ċ   imaginary part
    ×  multiply by input (vectorize)
```

### Proof of algorithm

Let the polynomial be `f(x)`.

Since we are guaranteed that if `x` is a root then so is `-x`, so `f` must be even, meaning that its coefficient for the odd powers must be `0`.

Now, rotating the roots by `90°` is essentially `f(ix)`.

Expanding then comparing coefficients proves the algorithm.

Comment: So, we need not touch the 2,4th,6th, 8th etc?

Comment: Those are zero anyway.

Comment: Your trick with `ı*Ċ` is very nice, you should explain it :)

Comment: @Leo It's essentially a straightforward implementation though...

Comment: The logic here is not quite right, because you can instead have all coefficients for *even* powers be 0.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Are you saying that the coefficients for *odd* powers can be non-zero?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Could you give me an example?

Comment: `x^5 - x^3 + x`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen You're right. You should talk to flawr about that.

Comment: I already did, we cleared it up in the comments and then deleted them again. Note that the test cases are in *descending* order.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 25 bytes

```
a=>a.map((e,i)=>i%4?-e:e)
```

The original polynomial has solutions of the form `x = ±a` where a lies on the real or imaginary line. Except when `a = 0` (in which case `x` is a factor of the polynomial), this means that `x² - a²` is a factor of the polynomial (which means alternate terms are always zero). Now when we rotate the roots, the factor changes to `x² + a²`. Since all the factors change at the same time, the third term of the polynomial, which is the sum of all the `-a²` terms, changes sign, the fifth term, which is the sum of products of pairs of `-a²` terms, keeps the same sign, etc. alternating every other term.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

```matlab
@(x)round(poly(roots(x)*j))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7PV09P776BRoVmUX5qXolGQn1OpUZSfX1IMFNLK0tT8n6YRbahgoGBoACR0DY3MQZSJGYhnam4Wq/kfAA)

This directly applies the definition: compute roots, multiply by `j`, convert back from roots to polynomial. A final rounding is necessary because of floating-point numerical errors.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,s=1:x and[0,x[0]*s]+f(x[2:],-s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#NYzNCoAgEIRfZY9ZK6j0A4JPInswRAjKIjvs21sUnb6Zj2FqcmvY5hiAsThtGUKOXiF7RW2hLjXsjSWURdS0n8CwZPAaQSFo9UJqM32hHz8zTCPhv5L9g7eSheNc8tU8p0LUGw)

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), <s>71</s> 66 bytes

```
readIO
b=i
lbla
readIO
d=c
d&2
i=i*(1-d)
printInt i
b-1
c+1
if b a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcc7CoAwEEXR/q0ilfghkBHRKgtI5RryURgIKib7H1PY3MMtnO8i8h4@uR3BMnLIHv8nG5G6GWx57EmnAc/LV3VXVYygCXEi8KmC8iKyCYkRMi2a5q2xrOYD)

<s>I have no clue what wizardry @Leaky Nun did here to save 5 bytes.</s>

Took me a second to figure out, but The second bit of C will alternate like we want. Therefore @Leaky Nun exploited this to save the bits we need.

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##Lcc7CoAwEEXR/q0ilfghkBHRKgtI5RryURgIKib7H1PY3MMtnO8i8h4@uR3BMnLIHv8nG5G6GWx57EmnAc/LV3VXVYygCXEi8KmC8iKyCYkRMi2a5q2xrOYD)

Answer (score 0):

## Casio-Basic, 8 bytes

```
n|x=x
```

Unnamed function, using Ian Miller's Mathematica approach. The imaginary  from the Math2 keyboard needs to be used (counts as 2 bytes, char code 769), and the polynomial should be entered as an equation of `x`.

7 bytes for the code, 1 byte to specify `n` as a parameter.

**Explanation**: Takes the equation `n`, then simply replaces all instances of `x` with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
p->x=I*x;eval(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8L9A167C1lOrwjq1LDFHo0Dzf0FRZl6JRppGRZyFgraCoYFWRZyZgq6CoZE5kGUCZJmYgcSMgJKm5maamv8B)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 20 bytes

```
seq(real(i^X/i)Ans(X),X,1,dim(Ans
```

If stored in `prgmA`, run with:

```
{1, 0, 3, 0, 1}:prgmA
```

`seq(` just had to be the *one** command that doesn't support complex numbers. :)

<sub>*: Exaggeration</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Æ[]▐↨
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=925b5dde17&i=%5B1+0+10+0+-127+0+-460+0+576%5D%0A%5B1+0+-4+0%5D%0A%5B1%5D&a=1&m=2)

Port of the Jelly answer.

Uses ASCII representation to explain:

```
mih|1*
m         Map each element with rest of program, print mapped results on individual lines
 i        Current 0-based loop index
  h       Floor(i/2)
   |1     (-1)^(i/2)
     *    Multiply with current element
```

If there can be leading zeros, they need to be trimmed first and it can be done at the cost of another byte.