# Symbolic Differentiation of Composed Functions

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, calculus

## Symbolic Differentiation 2: Back on the Chain Gang

### Task

Write a program that takes in a certain sort of function from stdin and differentiates it with respect to *x*, using the chain rule.* The input function will be a string of the following form:

```
"trig_1 trig_2 trig_3 ... x"
```

where `trig_n` is a trigonometric function `sin` or `cos`, and there are at most four functions in the term. The example string

```
"cos sin sin x"
```

represents the function cos(sin(sin(x))).

Your output must take the following form:

```
k(trig_1 trig_2 x)(trig_a trig_b trig_c x)(trig_m trig_n x) et cetera
```

where `k` is a constant and parentheses represent groups to be multiplied together.

*The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) states that `D[f(g(x))] = f'(g(x)) * g'(x)`

### Examples

```
"sin sin sin sin x" ==> 1(cos x)(cos sin x)(cos sin sin x)(cos sin sin sin x)
"cos x" ==> -1(sin x)
"cos sin x" ==> -1(cos x)(sin sin x)
```

### Scoring

Your score is the length of your program in bytes, multiplied by three if you use a built-in or a library that does symbolic algebra.

### Similar Challenges

[The previous installment: polynomial differentiation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54162/symbolic-differentiation-of-polynomials)
[Polynomial integration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66714/symbolic-integration-of-polynomials)
[General differentiation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/help-me-with-differential-calculus/31935#31935)

Comment: (Maybe [trigonometry] is an inappropriate tag?)

Comment: This is less of a [tag:calculus] question. It's more like a [tag:parsing] challenge than anything.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>224</s> 214 bytes

Let the games begin!

```
interface B{static void main(String[]a){String o="";int v=2,z=a.length-1,i=z,k;for(;i>0;o+="x)"){if(a[--i].equals("cos")){o+="(sin ";v=(v+2)%4;}else o+="(cos ";for(k=i;++k<z;)o+=a[k]+" ";}System.out.print(v-1+o);}}
```

This could (theoretically) extend infinitely.

Output for `sin cos sin sin cos sin cos sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x`:

```
1(cos x)(sin sin x)(sin cos sin x)(sin cos cos sin x)(cos cos cos cos sin x)(sin sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(sin sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(sin sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos cos sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(sin sin cos sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos cos sin cos sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos sin cos sin cos sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(sin sin sin cos sin cos sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)(cos cos sin sin cos sin cos sin sin sin cos sin sin cos sin cos cos cos sin x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## sed, 88 + 1 = <s>123</s> 89 bytes

`+1` for the `-r` (extended regex) flag.

```
s/^/d/
:
s/d(-?)sin (.*)/(\1cos \2)d\2/
s/d(-?)cos (.*)/(\1-sin \2)d\2/
s/--//
s/dx/1/
t
```

### Explanation

Note: A single `d` is used as short version of `d/dx` in the golfed program.

First, preceed the string with `d/dx`. Then, reapeat the following replacements until the string does not change anymore:

```
d/dx sin ...    => (cos ...)d/dx ...
d/dx cos ...    => (-sin ...)d/dx ...
d/dx -sin ...   => (-cos ...)d/dx ...
d/dx -cos ...   => (sin ...)d/dx ...
d/dx x          => 1
```

Edit: The positive and negative cases are now handled within a single regex. This requires an additional search and replace to drop a double minus and is less elegant, but way shorter.

Comment: Elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 115 bytes

```
ToExpression["d["<>StringReplace[#,{" "->"@"}]<>"]"]//.d[x_[y__]]->d[x][y]d[y]/.{d[sin]->cos,d[cos]->-sin,d[x]->1}&
```